# Javascript confusion for scope of 'this' inside closure function

Tags: javascript, oop, scope, this

I tried below function to understand `this` keyword scope global/private.

I understood it 97%. but got stuck in confusion over the output of **`x.private_fa()`** which returns a private function but not the private value inside it.

```js
a = 1.1;
b = 2.1;
c = 3.1;

function fa() {
  return "Global fa()";
}

function f() {
  var a = 1;
  this.b = 2;

  function fa() {
    return this.b; // or this.a not working..!
    //return b // 2.2
    //return a // 1
  }

  return {
    private_a: a, // 1
    global_a: window.a, // 1.1
    private_b: this.b, // 2
    global_b: b, // 2.1
    private_fax: fa(), // 2.1
    private_fa: fa, // function private fa()
    global_fa: window.fa(), // Global fa()
    global_c: c, // 3.1
    private_c: this.c // 3
  };
}

try {

  f.prototype.c = 3;

  var x = new f();

  f.prototype.c = 4;

  console.log("x:", x);

  /*??? Please explain this.. ??? */
  console.log("x.private_fa():", x.private_fa());

  console.log(x.private_c);
  var x1 = new f();
  console.log(x1.private_c);

  console.log(" - End - ");
} catch (e) {
  console.error("Error: ", e.message);
}
```

Comment: Assign it to another variable before entering the function, like `var b_internal = this.b` and then inside the closure you have `b_internal` that has the correct value.

Comment: Even better, if you need to access all the members (and maybe modify them), do the same with `this` as in `var t = this` and then inside the closure `return t.b;`

Comment: this is because `this` will refer to the context the function is called rather than where it is defined, and you can notice that there is no `a` or `b` property in the object you return in `f`, where `fa()` is called. you can either store the value in the function (closure) like Federico says, another way would be to use ES6's arrow function, that have a "stable" `this` that corresponds to where function is defined

Comment: Do not `return` an object from a constructor function that is called with `new`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you posted, a call to `x.private_fa()` returns `undefined`, just because the object x hasn't a `b` member (and fa returns `this.b`).

If you want it to return that value let your object's `private_fa` return a bound version of the "private" `fa()`:

```
var bound_fa = fa.bind(this);

return {
    private_a: a, // 1
    global_a: window.a, // 1.1
    private_b: this.b, // 2
    global_b: window.b, // 2.1
    private_fax: fa(), // 2.1
    private_fa: bound_fa, // function private fa()
    global_fa: window.fa(), // Global fa()
    global_c: window.c, // 3.1
    private_c: this.c // 3
};
```

In `bound_fa` function, `this` will be forever tied to `f()` context (where the desired variable `b` belongs).

This reading could clarify the *this* enigma further: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch1.md

Comment: Thanks, this answer looks professional and standard.